# How to save toggle button on custom ListView using JSON on Android?

Tags: java, android

My custom adapter for notification

```
public class SchoolTagAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    Context context;
    SharedPreferences prefs;
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    Boolean toggle_status;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;
    HashMap<String, String> resultp = new HashMap<String, String>();

    public SchoolTagAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arraylist) {
        this.context = context;
        data = arraylist;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return data.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }


    /********* Called when Item click in ListView ************/
    private class OnItemClickListener  implements OnClickListener
    {
      private int mPosition;

      OnItemClickListener(int position)
      {
        mPosition = position;
      }

      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) 
      {
         // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        SchoolDetails schoolDetail = (SchoolDetails)context;
        schoolDetail.onItemClick(mPosition);
      }
    }



    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        TextView id;
        TextView name;
        final ToggleButton toogle;

        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.schooltag_list, parent, false);
        // Get the position
        resultp = data.get(position);

        id = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        name = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.tagname);
        toogle = (ToggleButton)itemView.findViewById(R.id.toggleButton1);

        name.setText(resultp.get(SchoolDetails.NAME));

        SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
          toggle_status = preferences.getBoolean("NameOfThingToSave",true);
          Log.d("TOGGLE_STATUS", toggle_status+"");
          if(toggle_status==true)
          {
           toogle.setChecked(true);
           }
          else if(toggle_status==false)
          {
           toogle.setChecked(false);
           }

          toogle.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
            {   
              @Override
              public void onClick(View v) 
              {
                //TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if (toogle.isChecked()) 
                {
                  prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
                  SharedPreferences.Editor prefEditor = prefs.edit();
                  prefEditor.putBoolean("NameOfThingToSave",true);
                  prefEditor.commit();
                   }
                 else if(!toogle.isChecked())
                 {
                     prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
                      SharedPreferences.Editor prefEditor = prefs.edit();
                      prefEditor.putBoolean("NameOfThingToSave",false);
                      prefEditor.commit();
                   }  
                  }
                });

        itemView.setOnClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(position));

        return itemView;
    }

 }
```

This is my Activity

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import com.example.schoolzine.adapters.SchoolTagAdapter;
import com.example.schoolzine.asyncimages.ImageLoader;
import com.example.schoolzine.database.DatabaseHandler;
import com.example.schoolzine.models.SchoolTag;
import com.example.schoolzine.utils.JsonParsor;
import com.example.schoolzine.utils.WebserviceUtil;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class SchoolDetails extends Activity {

    public static String id;
    public int t,parn,stud,stff;
    TextView Name,City,State,Street,Tag;
    Button back, next;
    String schoolName,schoolStreet,schoolCity,schoolState,schoolImage,schoolId,schoolUrl,schoolid,
           schoolPOBox,schoolPhone,schoolWebsite,schoolPrefix,schoolURL,schoolnotId,schoolnotifName;
    int schoolnotifId;
    public String TAG1,TAG2,TAG3,spinnerValue;
    ImageView Image;
    ImageLoader SchoolImageLoader  = new ImageLoader(SchoolDetails.this);
    JSONObject jobject, jobj;
    public ProgressDialog p_dialog;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arraylist;
    Spinner spin;
    HashMap queryValues;
    DatabaseHandler dbHandler;
    SharedPreferences pref;
    boolean toggle_status;
    SharedPreferences preferences;

    public static String ID = "id";
    public static String NAME = "name";
    public static String DESCRIPTION = "description";

    ListView listview;
    SchoolTagAdapter sadapter;
    ArrayList<SchoolTag> schoolTAG;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_schooldetails);

        dbHandler = new DatabaseHandler(SchoolDetails.this);

        if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
           StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
           StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        }

        getActionBar().hide();

        Image = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.schoolimage);
        Name = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.name);
        Street = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.street);
        City = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.city);
        State = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.state);
        Tag = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tagname);
        listview = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        spin = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        back = (Button)findViewById(R.id.back);
        next = (Button)findViewById(R.id.next);

        schoolTAG = new ArrayList<SchoolTag>();

        preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
        toggle_status = preferences.getBoolean("NameOfThingToSave", false);

        if(WebserviceUtil.isConnectingToInternet(SchoolDetails.this)) {
           new SchoolDetailTask().execute(WebserviceUtil.WEBSERVICE_URL+"school/"+id+".json");  
           }

        spin.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if(arg2 == 0) {
//                 schoolTAG.clear();   
                   if(WebserviceUtil.isConnectingToInternet(SchoolDetails.this)) {
                      new SchoolNotifTag1Task().execute();  
                   }
//                 schoolTAG.clear();
//                sadapter = new SchoolTagAdapter(SchoolDetails.this, R.layout.schooltag_list, schoolTAG);
//                listview.setAdapter(sadapter);            
                }
                if(arg2 == 1) {
//                 schoolTAG.clear();
                   if(WebserviceUtil.isConnectingToInternet(SchoolDetails.this)) {
                      new SchoolNotifTag2Task().execute();  
                   }
//                 schoolTAG.clear();
//                sadapter = new SchoolTagAdapter(SchoolDetails.this, R.layout.schooltag_list, schoolTAG);  ;
//                listview.setAdapter(sadapter);    
                }
                if(arg2 == 2) {
//                 schoolTAG.clear();
                   if(WebserviceUtil.isConnectingToInternet(SchoolDetails.this)) {
                      new SchoolNotifTag3Task().execute();  
                   }
//                 schoolTAG.clear();
//                sadapter = new SchoolTagAdapter(SchoolDetails.this, R.layout.schooltag_list, schoolTAG);  ;
//                listview.setAdapter(sadapter);    
                }
             }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }

        });

        back.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
             // TODO Auto-generated method stub
             Intent inten = new Intent(SchoolDetails.this, StateSchoolList.class);
             startActivity(inten);
             finish();
            }
         });


        if(dbHandler.doesIdExist(id)) {
           next.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }     
        else {
        next.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "rawtypes" })
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
              // TODO Auto-generated method stub
              queryValues = new HashMap();

               queryValues.put("sId", schoolid);
               queryValues.put("sName", schoolName);
               queryValues.put("sStreet", schoolStreet);
               queryValues.put("sState", schoolState);
               queryValues.put("sCity", schoolCity);
               queryValues.put("sPOBox", schoolPOBox);
               queryValues.put("sPhone", schoolPhone);
               queryValues.put("sWebsite", schoolWebsite);
               queryValues.put("sImage", schoolImage);
               queryValues.put("sURL", schoolURL);
               queryValues.put("sPrefix", schoolPrefix);

              dbHandler.insertSchoolDetails(queryValues);

              Intent intent = new Intent(SchoolDetails.this, Registration.class);
              startActivity(intent);
             }
          });
        }

    }


    private class SchoolDetailTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> 
    {
        public ProgressDialog p_dialog;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            p_dialog = ProgressDialog.show(SchoolDetails.this, "Loading Data", "Please Wait...", true);
            p_dialog.setCancelable(true);
            p_dialog.show();
            super.onPreExecute();
          }

        @SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes" })
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            JsonParsor json = new JsonParsor();
            JSONObject jobject = json.getJSONFromUrl(WebserviceUtil.WEBSERVICE_URL+"school/"+id+".json");
            queryValues = new HashMap();

            try {
                JSONObject jobj = jobject.getJSONObject("school");
                   schoolid = jobj.getString("id");
                   schoolName = jobj.getString("name");
                   schoolStreet = jobj.getString("physical_street");
                   schoolCity = jobj.getString("physical_city");
                   schoolState = jobj.getString("physical_state");
                   schoolPOBox = jobj.getString("physical_postcode");
                   schoolPhone = jobj.getString("phone");
                   schoolWebsite = jobj.getString("website");
                   schoolPrefix = jobj.getString("prefix");
                   schoolImage = jobj.getString("logo");
                   schoolURL = jobj.getString("url");
             }
            catch (Exception e) {
             // TODO: handle exception
             e.printStackTrace();   
             }
            return "sucess";
          }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(p_dialog != null) {
               p_dialog.dismiss();
            }
//          sadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            if(result.compareTo("sucess") == 0) {
              Name.setText(schoolName);
              Street.setText(schoolStreet);
              City.setText(schoolCity);
              State.setText(schoolState);
              SchoolImageLoader.DisplayImage(schoolImage, Image);
            }
         }

    }


    private class SchoolNotifTag1Task extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        public ProgressDialog p_dialog;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            p_dialog = ProgressDialog.show(SchoolDetails.this, "Loading Data", "Please Wait...", true);
            p_dialog.setCancelable(true);
            p_dialog.show();
            super.onPreExecute();
          }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            arraylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

            JsonParsor json = new JsonParsor();
            JSONObject jobject = json.getJSONFromUrl(WebserviceUtil.SCHOOL_NOTIF_TAG1);

            try {
                JSONArray jarray = jobject.getJSONArray("groups");
                System.out.println("TAG1_JARRAY = "+jarray);
                for (int i=0; i<jarray.length(); i++) {
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    JSONObject jobj = jarray.getJSONObject(i);
                        map.put("id", jobj.getString("id"));
                        map.put("name", jobj.getString("name"));
                        map.put("description", jobj.getString("description"));
                    arraylist.add(map);
                }

            }
            catch (Exception e) {
              // TODO: handle exception
              e.printStackTrace();  
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            p_dialog.dismiss();
            listview = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
            sadapter = new SchoolTagAdapter(SchoolDetails.this, arraylist);
            listview.setAdapter(sadapter);
        }

     }


    private class SchoolNotifTag2Task extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        public ProgressDialog p_dialog;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            p_dialog = ProgressDialog.show(SchoolDetails.this, "Loading Data", "Please Wait...", true);
            p_dialog.setCancelable(true);
            p_dialog.show();
            super.onPreExecute();
          }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            arraylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

            JsonParsor json = new JsonParsor();
            JSONObject jobject = json.getJSONFromUrl(WebserviceUtil.SCHOOL_NOTIF_TAG2);

            try {
                JSONArray jarray = jobject.getJSONArray("groups");
                System.out.println("TAG2_JARRAY = "+jarray);
                for (int i=0; i<jarray.length(); i++) {
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    JSONObject jobj = jarray.getJSONObject(i);
                        map.put("id", jobj.getString("id"));
                        map.put("name", jobj.getString("name"));
                        map.put("description", jobj.getString("description"));
                    arraylist.add(map);
                }

            }
            catch (Exception e) {
              // TODO: handle exception
              e.printStackTrace();  
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            p_dialog.dismiss();
            listview = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
            sadapter = new SchoolTagAdapter(SchoolDetails.this, arraylist);
            listview.setAdapter(sadapter);
        }

     }


    private class SchoolNotifTag3Task extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        public ProgressDialog p_dialog;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            p_dialog = ProgressDialog.show(SchoolDetails.this, "Loading Data", "Please Wait...", true);
            p_dialog.setCancelable(true);
            p_dialog.show();
            super.onPreExecute();
          }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            arraylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

            JsonParsor json = new JsonParsor();
            JSONObject jobject = json.getJSONFromUrl(WebserviceUtil.SCHOOL_NOTIF_TAG3);

            try {
                JSONArray jarray = jobject.getJSONArray("groups");
                System.out.println("TAG3_JARRAY = "+jarray);
                for (int i=0; i<jarray.length(); i++) {
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    JSONObject jobj = jarray.getJSONObject(i);
                        map.put("id", jobj.getString("id"));
                        map.put("name", jobj.getString("name"));
                        map.put("description", jobj.getString("description"));
                    arraylist.add(map);
                }

            }
            catch (Exception e) {
              // TODO: handle exception
              e.printStackTrace();  
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            p_dialog.dismiss();
            listview = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
            sadapter = new SchoolTagAdapter(SchoolDetails.this, arraylist);
            listview.setAdapter(sadapter);
        }

     }

    public static void values(String ID) {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      id = ID;  
     }

    public void onItemClick(int mPosition) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        toggle_status = preferences.getBoolean("NameOfThingToSave", true);

        if (toggle_status == true) {
//          Toast.makeText(SchoolDetails.this, "Toogle "+toggle_status+" at position "+mPosition,
//                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//        player.start();
//        Log.d("MUSIC pLAYER", "STARTED");
          }
        else if (toggle_status == false) {
//          Toast.makeText(SchoolDetails.this, "Toogle "+toggle_status+" at position "+mPosition,
//                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//        player.stop();
//        Log.d("MUSIC pLAYER", "STOPPED");
          }
      }

 }
```

I tried to parse JSON values into a custom `ListView`.

My custom `ListView` contains a `TextView` and a toggle button. It's a notification activity. I turn notifications on and off by using a toggle button in a custom `ListView`.

The JSON values parsed fine. I limited my `ListView` height to 150dp.

My problem is that, suppose if my `ListView` contains 20 values parsed. When I put on first list item and when I scrolled down, the last few items also automatically turned on. I think it may because of recreating `ListView`, but I don’t know how to solve it.

What I want is to save state of each toggle button in `ListView` I turned on/off.

Anybody have any idea?

Comment: you need to place tagging inside your custom list adapter

Comment: show me your code then i will tell you where you need to place tag.

Comment: please show us your code.

Comment: hi daniel, i posted my code. please help

Comment: got the answer after a long research.. lol.. its just pure database idea..

Answer (score 0):

```
if (convertView == null) {
    //inflating views
    convertView.setTag(holder);
}
else {
    holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
}
```